# Email conflict while login by different socials

Tags: django

I have python-django backend, that allows u to sign in through fb, apple, email, google. My email field is unique, so I can't have more than one user with single email.
When user sign in with socials I take his email and create new user.
Problem is, if u have two socials with single email, u can't use both of them to sign in. It works like:

We have Facebook and appleId with same email
Sign in with apple -> I create user with appleId, name, email -> user press logout -> user press sign in with Facebook -> I can't create new user because I have that email in db already.

So the question is, what should I do and where I can find examples of it.

**Details**: I have custom Django User and I have to take email in any case. I can't use Django-social.

I think on the last step I should give user profile, that was made in second step, but I don't know how to google this problem and how its done common practice

Answer (score 0):

when someone logs in through FB or Google and its email not present in the local account, It creates a new social account. If the email present in local accounts matches with google or Facebook accounts while logging in through this, it only authenticates it (no need to put local account password). I also saved few things into the User during @receiver(user_signed_up).
This code solved the conflict between same google and Facebook using the same email id
I did not use verification, you can use it if you want

```
class MyAppSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
# login(request, user) Before we did this
@transaction.atomic
def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):

    # social account already exists, so no need to do anything Auto login will happen
    if sociallogin.is_existing:
        return

    # some social logins don't have an email address, e.g. facebook accounts
    # with mobile numbers only, but allauth takes care of this case so just
    # ignore it
    if 'email' not in sociallogin.account.extra_data:
        return

    # find the first verified email that we get from this sociallogin
    # verified_email = None
    # for email in sociallogin.email_addresses:
    #     if email.verified:
    #         verified_email = email
    #         break
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=sociallogin.email_addresses[0])
        # This user now can be authenticated without password through google or facebook
        sociallogin.connect(request, user)
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(redirect('logout_process'))  # send it back to login
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    # if social account does not exist, it creates one by default
```